# Swipe the screens for next pages

Tags: codenameone

I am looking for the container swipe, we have list of records 20. we are showing in first screen 1 to 10 while swiping we need to next 11 to 20 records. We are using Container to show records. Is there any way to handle horizontal swipe for Container.

Thanks in advance

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you are looking for side swipe then [Tabs](https://www.codenameone.com/javadoc/com/codename1/ui/Tabs.html) is designed with that use case in mind e.g. see the carousel sample in the link. Notice you can hide the tabs and only allow swipe.